# usb 1-1.6: device descriptor read/64, error -110

Tags: linux, usb, dmesg

## Context

`Linux 4.7.6-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Sep 30 19:28:42 CEST 2016 x86_64`

I'm using `GDM` with autologin

> I tested with XFCE and GNOME as window managers

## Problem

#### autologin enabled

I get to a black screen with only the message `usb 1-1.6: device descriptor read/64, error -110` then, after some time, gdm loads (what shouldn't happen, as the autologin was enabled).

#### autologin disabled

My system starts normally, but the error still happens in `dmesg`.

```
[    3.110683] hid-generic 0003:1532:0015.0003: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Razer Razer Naga] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input1
[    3.110714] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[    3.110715] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[    3.116465] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp1s0: link is not ready
[    3.145364] input: HDA Digital PCBeep as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input9
[    3.146076] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input20
[    3.237392] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc
[    3.894440] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 170x48
[    3.948786] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
[    5.730958] ACPI: Battery Slot [BAT0] (battery present)
[    5.731897] ACPI: AC Adapter [ADP1] (on-line)
[    5.747141] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input21
[    5.747249] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input22
[    5.747530] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input23
[    6.700771] random: nonblocking pool is initialized

// the problem is here
[    7.960730] usb 1-1.6: device descriptor read/64, error -110 

[   19.960272] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp1s0: link is not ready
[   20.909436] wlp1s0: authenticate with 00:1a:3f:7f:6f:b4
[   20.926085] wlp1s0: send auth to 00:1a:3f:7f:6f:b4 (try 1/3)
[   20.927918] wlp1s0: authenticated
[   20.931334] wlp1s0: associate with 00:1a:3f:7f:6f:b4 (try 1/3)
[   20.935559] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from 00:1a:3f:7f:6f:b4 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=2)
[   20.935632] wlp1s0: associated
[   20.935674] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp1s0: link becomes ready
[   21.290494] fuse init (API version 7.25)
```

Comment: And what kind of device is behind the "usb 1-1.6" port? Any reference to a problem with device descriptor is usually an indication that corresponding USB device died for some reason, modem crashed, or something.

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance, but how can I find what is behind the "usb 1-1.6" port?

Comment: You need to examine your logs when the 1-1.6 device appears first time, when it gets enumerated. There should be more information.

Comment: By logs you don't mean `dmesg`?

Comment: If the "usb 1-1.6" fault appears in something called "dmesg", then the enumeration also should appear there. I have no idea, you need to find a Linux expert on how to get kernel logs with proper USB-related verbosity.

Comment: seems that 'error -110' means 'power exceeded' as of [this answer at stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13661508/574981)